# How to create a Test class with parameters?

Tags: python, pytest

Here is what the current test code looks like:

```
def do_simulation(speed):
    df = run_simulation(speed)

    # following is a lot of assert that checks the values in df
    assert df["X"].iloc[0] == 0
    assert df["Y"].iloc[-1] == 2
    assert ...
    ....

def test_simulation():
    do_simulation(100)
    do_simulation(200)
```

I want to convert the test code to a Test class:

```
class TestSimulation(object):

    def setup_class(cls):
        cls.df = run_simulation(100) # I want to change the speed parameter

    def test_1():
        "comment 1"
        assert self.df["X"].iloc[0] == 0

    def test_2():
        "comment 2"
        assert self.df["Y"].iloc[-1] == 2
```

I read the document of py.test, but I can't figure out how to run TestSimulation for speed in [100, 200, ...].
the `setup_class()` method can only have `cls` argument.

What I want is a Test class that:

- call `do_simulation()` once, and store the result.
- call all the test method to check the simulation result.
- I can different parameters to `do_simulation()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [pytest fixture and parametrize](https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixture-parametrize) it:

```
@pytest.fixture(
    scope='module', # so that it's reused in the module scope
    params=[100, 200]
)
def simulation(request):
    speed = request.param
    # create the simulation
    return df

class Test:

    def test1(self, simulation):
        ...

    def test2(self, simulation):
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know when py.test do the gc collection? Because the simulation results are very big. I don't have enough memory If it keeps all the results when params is very long.